# How to calculate input values from a vector of rolling sums in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a unique problem where I need to calculate input values behind a vector of rolling sums. For example, I have an hourly data feed from a sensor as follows:

```
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 01:00:00"), 
                                as.POSIXct("2022-01-10 23:00:00"), by = "hour"), 
                 val = round(runif(239, 0, 40), 0)) %>% 
  mutate(day = day(datetime)) %>% 
  mutate(roll_sum = roll_sum(lag(val), 24, align = "right", fill = NA))
```

What I want to do is to calculate `predicted values` from the `roll_sum` column. Because in the actual dataset, only rolling sums are available.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You can't - rolling sums lose information. If you knew the values that go into any one window then you could work it out, but without those you're out of luck.

Comment: It's easy to see if you consider a small example. Let's say the window size is 2, and the rolling sum values are `1, 2, 3`. Some inputs that could produce this result: `{0, 1, 1, 2}`, `{1, 0, 2, 1}`, `{2, -1, 3, -1}`, `{3, -2, 4, -1}`. Notice my start values are 0, 1, 2, 3 in these examples - pick any start value (`window_size - 1` start values in the general case) and you can construct a sequence that produces the output.

Comment: This may be beyond a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a genetic algorithm to find good initial conditions. It fit the cumulative series perfectly but did not match the actual initial conditions. This shows that this the solution is not unique.

```r
# decompose rolling sum

library(RcppRoll)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
# install.packages(c("devtools","pkgbuild"))
# library(pkgbuild)
# devtools::install_github("luca-scr/GA",build_vignettes=T)
library(GA) 

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 01:00:00"), 
                                as.POSIXct("2022-01-10 23:00:00"), by = "hour"), 
                 val = round(runif(239, 0, 40), 0)) %>% 
  mutate(day = day(datetime)) %>% 
  mutate(roll_sum = roll_sum(val, 24, align = "right", fill = NA))

# create a fit function using guess of val[1:24]
guess <- runif(24) * 41
fit <- function(guess, returnall = FALSE){
  n <- length(guess)
  df$val2 <- NA
  df$val2[1:n] <- floor(guess) # convert to integer
  for (i in (n+1):nrow(df)){
    df$val2[i] <- df$roll_sum[i] - df$roll_sum[i - 1] + df$val2[i - 24]
  }
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(roll_sum2 = roll_sum(val2, 24, align = "right", fill = NA))
  misfit <- sum((df$roll_sum2 - df$roll_sum) ^ 2, na.rm = TRUE) / 1000
  misfit <- misfit + sum(-df$val2[df$val2 < 0], na.rm = TRUE) 
  misfit <- misfit + sum(df$val2[df$val2 > 40] - 40, na.rm = TRUE) 
  if (returnall){
    return(list(guess = guess, df = df, misfit = -misfit))
  } else {
    return(-misfit)
  }
}
fit(guess) # test
#> [1] -590.104

# genetic algorithm to find best guess
gann <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
           fitness = fit, 
           lower = rep(0,24), 
           upper = rep(40,24),
           popSize = 100, 
           maxiter = 1000,
           keepBest = TRUE,
           seed = 123, 
           parallel = FALSE)

# evaluate
bestguess <- gann@solution[1,]
fit(bestguess) # check = 0
#> [1] 0
bestdf <- fit(bestguess, returnall = TRUE)$df 

ggplot(bestdf) +
  geom_point(aes(x = datetime, y = roll_sum, colour = "Original")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = datetime, y = roll_sum2, colour = "Bestfit")) 
#> Warning: Removed 23 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 23 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(bestdf) +
  labs(x = "Original", y = "Bestfit") +
  geom_point(aes(x = val, y = val2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>